# How can I display an Android textView in my form?

Tags: android, codenameone

I'm trying to display a simple Native Android textView in my form, but I am unable to get the textView to draw. I am using the following code:

```
public android.widget.TextView createNativeView() {
   android.widget.TextView dynamicTextView = new android.widget.TextView(AndroidNativeUtil.getContext());
   dynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   dynamicTextView.setText(" Hello World ");
   dynamicTextView.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
   return dynamicTextView;
}
```

With this I create a peerComponent 'view', to represent this textView on the form:

```
public void start() {
  if(current != null){
      current.show();
      return;
  }

  Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
  TestNativeInterface n = (TestNativeInterface)NativeLookup.create(TestNativeInterface.class);

  Button connect = new Button("connect","connect");
  Button start = new Button("start","start");
  start.addActionListener(e -> Dialog.show("Title", n.test("front", "back"), "OK", null));
  PeerComponent view = n.createNativeView();

  hi.add(new Label(view.getNativePeer().getClass().getSimpleName()));
  hi.add(view);
  hi.add(connect);
  hi.add(start);

  hi.show();
}
```

The label correctly displays with the text 'Text View', the buttons are being drawn and the simple actionListner works, but the textView is hidden on the form. As I understand CN1 components, the Native elements are drawn **after** the CN1 elements.

It feels like I may be missing a piece of the puzzle. Is there something like a .draw() function needed for native elements? How can I get this text view to display?

Testing on Samsung A5, Android 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred size method of Codename One components happens on the Codename One thread. The Android native equivalent method happens on the native Android event dispatch thread so when you added the component the preferred size was 0 hence the component remained invisible.

You can use this code which ignores the preferred size:

```
Form myForm = new Form("Native", new BorderLayout());
TestNativeInterface n = TestNativeInterface)NativeLookup.create(TestNativeInterface.class);
if(n != null && n.isSupported()) {
    PeerComponent view = n.createNativeView();
    myForm.add(CENTER, view);
}
myForm.show();
```

Notice that placing a component in the way that you did is inadvisable. We support peer components for "big ticket" items. E.g. Maps, Browser, Video etc.

All of them handle their own scrolling/gesture behavior. That makes them integrate better with our lightweight widgets.